# Formas de Substituir <Iframe> no HTML

Tags: html

Tenho um código que não funciona no IE8 e queria arranjar uma forma de de por a funcionar com outro código qualquer. nem que seja jquery.

HTML:

```
<center><table border="0">
<tr border="0">
<td border="0">
<iframe class="TbRH" src="RH/RH.PDF"   ></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table></center>
```

CSS:

```
width:100%; height:1140px;
border:none;overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-Y:hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ojcfofb0/

Comment: Por que seu código nao funciona? o que acontece? o que deveria acontecer?

Comment: Não mostra o PDF no IE8. Por isso queria colocar um codigo que funciona-se em todos os Browser incluindo o IE8

Comment: O PDF vai ser sempre o mesmo? por que não uma imagem?

Comment: Por vezes é necessario alterar. e é sempre mais facil alterar atraves do PDF.

Comment: `<center>` com `<table>`? você já pensou em ler sobre webstandards e tentar [bootstraps](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: pensei em lhe sugerir o PDF.js, porém o mesmo não dá suporte ao IE8. Eu entendo a sua frustação em ter que dá suporte ao IE8. ele deveria vir com a opção "Instalar novas versões automaticamente" como default.

Comment: Pois so que em alguns computadores não passa do IE8. Mas pronto

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja mais simples do que parece, tente isso:

### CSS

```
iframe {
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Já tentei isso e continua a não funcionar ..

Comment: tem algum script sendo bloqueado no console log ?

Comment: Não tem nada a ser bloqueado acho eu

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem seu problema a solução é colocar `display:block` e ao invés de `overflow-x` e `overflow-y` com o valor `hidden` use apenas `overflow`, segue o código:

```css
.TbRH {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1140px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <iframe class="TbRH" src="teste/teste.PDF"></iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

Acredito que isso resolva.

Answer (score 1):

A tabela não faz absolutamente nada.

Remova-a e defina o tamanho no próprio `iframe`.

O CSS também é desnecessário.

Remova tudo e use apenas assim:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="1140" src="teste/teste.PDF"></iframe>
```

Observação: Mesmo no Chrome, última versão, não funciona o script que postou. Não é algo específico do IE8.